# Forwarding data from server to router to Arduino

Tags: networking, arduino, router

Basically I have an Arduino UNO that I have connected via Ethernet to my router. I have logged the IP with my server and I would like to push data to my arduino. I guess the flow of data would be to send data (not sure the best way? Should I just open up a port and stream the data?) to the router that then forwards it to my Arduino at a local address assigned by my router.

How can I tell the router to forward this information on without logging in and changing anything with the router. The point of this exercise is to do everything with code and not do any other activities like logging into the router and setting things up. I want to do this as I have my Arduino recording temperature and I want to push data to state if it should switch sending the data from degrees or Fahrenheit or visa versa.

Comment: Better way is to call the server in a frequency to check the format of data. If you need to connect to a port of Arduino from internet, you need to configure port forwarding in your router

Comment: Is there no way around this? what about communicating by sending http posts is this possible?I wanted to reduce network traffic as the arduino will making lots of requests otherwise as I would like the update to be instantaneous

Answer (score 2):

I would use a socket server with a publish/subscribe pattern. Probably several out there but I know XSockets.NET best.

A few hours ago I actually connected my Arduino to XSockets and communicated between webpages and my arduino both ways.

I will put the code on github when I am done, but you can look at a video showing the concept here: [The Stuff For You Starts At 3:20](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbviMZ9dFE8)

Comment: OMG this is awesome. I have not selected chossen answer as I want to see if anyone else comes back with alternatives. Many thanks though and if you put the stuff of github will be totally stoked :D

Comment: Thanks. I will put all code on github with an example on how to do publish/subscribe between an arduino/netduino and browsers etc. May take a week or two since I have to write it all first :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to open any ports as long as your arduino and server is on the same local network. Since IP adresses maps all devices on a network including your arduino.

The reason you want to open ports on your router is to make people outside your local network access a server on your network. Reasons why port forwarding exists is that when someone sends a packet of data to your public IP (which is your router) it doesent know which local IP to send the packet to. It then discards it, unless you port forward a port to a local IP, which means your router sends all packets with that port to that local IP adress.

You also need to make your own server program, for example a java program to act as a server.

I made something similar to what you are looking for, but i use a wifi shield instead. I've had some problems with maintaining connections with it, but so far it seems that it's a problem with the wifi libary.

You still might learn something from it though:
[Maintaining communication between Arduino and Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287087/maintaining-communication-between-arduino-and-java-program)

If you want to know more about how the java server works in general, here is a great tutorial which explains a lot of the basics:
http://www.thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=25&number=38