# Possible to call methods from an Arduino library from java?

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx, led

I have written a program controlling my led stripes from Arduino, using a library which I modified to work with my stripes. The thing is now that I want to advance (network and stuff). Since I'm decent Java developer this would be so much easier in Java. I know that you can control an Arduino with Java, using RXTX library. The problem is that it might be a problem, rewriting/translating the library I currently use with my Arduino.

So my question is: is it possible to gain some kind of access to the Arduino library i have used for my led strips from Java? For example running a program on the Arduino which I can give input to from a java program. Like three, 3 digit int.

Thanks

Edit: Tried to give a better explanation, heck in comments. Hope it made it clearer.

Comment: Im not really sure what you are asking... Is this any insight? http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java

Comment: Thanks, but read that already. I will try to re-formulate my question. I currently have a library for my Arduino I downloaded and modified (made by some developer, not from "Arduino team"). I use this library to control the LED's. Without this library I'm not 100% sure how to control the lights. My question is: Is it possible to use this library from a java program/code to control my LED's? Or somehow get them to communicate.

Comment: That should be possible with JNI. I've tried something like this a time ago (not arduino, just C library) but was not able to make it work.

Comment: I'm in the making of a Arduino and Java program that communicates using the WiFi Shield. You might wanna take a look here for an example of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287087/maintaining-communication-between-arduino-and-java-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. This code below is for sending and receiving data to my Arduino.

```
public class IOData extends Observable implements SerialPortEventListener {

public SerialPort serialPort;
public String received = "tom";
/** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String portName = "/dev/tty.usbmodem1421"; //Change to whatever port your arduino is connected to.

public static BufferedReader input;
public static OutputStream output;

/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
public static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
public static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

//Prepare for receiving/sending
public void initialize() {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    // First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();

        if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
            portId = currPortId;
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {

        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        char ch = 1;
        output.write(ch);

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}
    //This is called when receiving data from an Arduino.
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        String temp = "empty";
        try {
            temp = input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Received this: " + temp);
        received = temp;

    //          setChanged();
   //           notifyObservers();

    }

}
    //This simply sends the data
public static synchronized void writeData(String data) {
    System.out.println("Sent: " + data);
    try {
        output.write(data.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not write to port");
    }
}
```

This is example code you can run on your Arduino (very simple code) does't do much, but you can build on it.

```
    int led = 13;

   void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    }
   void loop(){
   delay(100);
    }

   void serialEvent() {
   int inc = 0;
   while (Serial.available()){
   inc = Serial.parseInt();

   }
   Serial.print("Works");
   Serial.print(inc);

   }
```

Hope it helped if someone has the some problem.